# Tag for climbing gym?

Tags: discussion, tags

While we're on the subject of climbing tags, during my recent question I was surprised to find no tags for climbing gym. I did, however, see [a comment on this answer](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142/climbing-tags-to-be-merged/337#comment323_337) about adding a climbing gym tag but at the time no questions were relevant.

> @manoftheson I would be happy with a gym-climbing tag, actually. I just took a look, and no one has asked any questions that would fit there yet. But they haven't asked ice-climbing questions either. gym-climbing would be very useful; I am always looking to learn more about training for climbing. – theJollySin

Today, there are numerous climbing gym questions.

Are we ready for a climbing gym tag?

Comment: I think many topics are covered by [tag:sport-climbing]. Only questions that are specific to indoor climbing but not specific to either lead or bouldering would not fit in there. Maybe that is enough?

Comment: @imsodin there are several questions here specifically relating to climbing gyms that don't apply to outdoor climbing, like how to vet a belayer at the gym, how to train with limited gym layouts, etc. Just a thought.